# Domain of $(f \circ g)(x)$ when $f(x) = x^2 + 9$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x + 3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in need of some help. Right now I am doing some test corrections for my Honors High School Pre-calc class. This class is Algebra-based calculus. So the question is:

> Find $(f\circ g)(x)$ and its domain when $f(x)=x^2+9$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x+3}$.

I solved $(f\circ g)(x)$ to get $x+12$. So I understand how to get $(f\circ g)(x)$, but I do not understand how to get the domain. According to my test, it says that answer for the domain is $[-3,\infty)$. When I graph it on Desmos.com and my TI-84 Plus I get a straight line, so I really don't know how they got that answer. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain of this function is indeed $[-3, \infty)$, assuming $\sqrt[]{x}$ is undefined when $x<0$.

This is because $$(f\circ g)(x) = \left[\sqrt[]{x+3}\right]^2+3.$$ Notice that when $x < -3$, we are taking the square root of a negative number, which is undefined. Therefore, the only values of $x$ for which $(f\circ g)(x)$ is defined are those satisfying $x \geq -3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Austin Weaver! That makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

Let $D(f)$ be a domain of the function $f$.

Thus, by definition we have:
$$D(f\circ g)=D(g)\cap\{x|g(x)\in D(f)\}$$
In our case 
$$f(g(x))=\left(\sqrt{x+3}\right)^2+9,$$
$$D(f)=\mathbb R$$ and $$D(g)=[-3,+\infty).$$

Thus, the domain is $[-3,+\infty)$.

Comment: +1 from me as compensation. I don't know who and why downvoted your answer as it is exactly same as accepted answer and came even earlier

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra The accepted answer has *explanation* and *pedagogy*, rather than just showing off that the answerer knows the answer. Hence my downvote.

Comment: @user296602 See please better my solution. I explained what is it $D(f\circ g)$ and by this definition wrote the answer.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg An explanation would be something like Austin Weaver's answer, that talks about *why* the domain is what it is and how you found it, rather than just some notation (that the asker probably has *no* idea what it is) and "Thus the answer is..." Compare your answer with the answer that actually talks about what the issues are.

Comment: @user296602 I don't agree with you. I think an explanation  should be right.  And if there are questions about an explanation then it needs to ask these questions. If you don't understand something in my answer you can can ask me and I am ready to explain. I think down votes like your they are very bad for this site.

Comment: @user296602 3 I tried to understand what maybe you did not understood and I fixed something. Thank you for your  sincerity.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm not the asker, and I *do* understand your answer. I just don't think it's a very good one, because it doesn't have even a single written sentence explaining *why* it's the correct answer. Answers should be reasonably self-contained, and not need follow-up questions from the poster.

Comment: @user296602 Which I did. By the way,  I think BlazeRyder is teacher (it follows from his post). Also, if my answer is clear for you then  why did you down vote?

Comment: I already explained why: I downvoted your answer because I do not believe it is a high-quality answer that *teaches* something. It just states an answer and almost nothing else. This is also far from the first time that I've left comments to this effect on your posts and had this conversation, so next time I'll just vote and move on. (And "doing test corrections" almost surely means that the asker is a student correcting their own work, *not* a teacher grading.)

Comment: @user296602 You can do what you think is right, but I don't agree with your concept and I think this concept is very bad for this site. I think in the first place should be math.